# When using gets to get a file name in C, the file opens but when using fgets it does not

Tags: c, file, fopen

I'm trying, in C, to get a string from user input so the program can open a chosen file.

I tried using fgets because I read on numerous threads that it is the safer option (as opposed to gets).

However when a string is stored using gets, the file opens, but with fgets it does not.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
char csvFile[256];
FILE *inpfile;

printf("Please enter CSV filename: ");
fgets(csvFile,256,stdin);

printf("\nFile is %s\n",csvFile);

inpfile = fopen(csvFile,"r");

if(inpfile == NULL)
{
    printf("File cannot be opened!");
}
```

I know the file exists but with fgets the if block is entered.
The only difference is that using:

```
gets(csvFile);
```

works in place of

```
fgets(csvFile,256,stdin);
```

Can anyone help me make sense of this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [man fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) says:  If a newline is read, ***it is stored into the buffer***.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the trailing newline:

```
char csvFile[256], *p;

fgets(csvFile, sizeof csvFile, stdin);
if ((p = strchr(csvFile, '\n')) != NULL) { 
    *p = '\0'; /* remove newline */
}
```

Comment: So basically get the pointer to the '\n' in the string and then change the value at that address?

Comment: Surely also csvFile[strlen(csvFile)-1] = '\0';

Answer (score 1):

You can check the newline character at the end of `csvFile` by adding for example two "=" at the first and end of your sentence, respectively.

```
printf("\n=File is %s=\n",csvFile);
```

You can easily remove the newline character at the end of `csvFile` using `strtok()` function from `<string.h>` library. So you may need to add one line of code after reading the input string with `fgets()` in the following manner:

```
fgets(csvFile, sizeof csvFile, stdin);
strtok(csvFile, "\n");
```

Comment: This works well too, I do prefer it to Alter Mann's suggestion as it doesn't require a pointer declaration. Although both are valid.

Comment: @james02, The `strtok` function doesn't work as expected if the user enters an empty string (i.e. presses only Enter). It leaves the \n character intact, furthermore, uses a static buffer while parsing and is not thread-safe, [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/1606345)

Answer (score 0):

The difference you observed between `fgets` and `gets` is that `fgets` leaves the newline character at the end of the read string. But it should not cause you to going back to `gets` - just remove the last character in `csvFile` if it is newline.